# In IE 8 dates are NaN/Nan/Nan

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-8

In IE8 my dates are not appearing properly. I have tried many implementations but they are not working properly. Here is what I had originally that works in FF, Chrome and IE9.

```
var date = TranslateDate(new Date(CreatedDate);
```

where CreatedDate is a c# datetime object.

```
function TranslateDate(d) {
    return GetMonth(d) + '/' + GetDay(d) + '/' + d.getFullYear();
}

function GetMonth(d) {
    var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
    return (('' + month).length < 2 ? '0' : '') + month;
}

function GetDay(d) {
    var day = d.getDate();
    return (('' + day).length < 2 ? '0' : '') + day;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What exactly is the format of `CreatedDate`?

Comment: IE8 does not support that date format. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11020658/javascript-json-date-parse-in-ie7-ie8-returns-nan

Comment: Is there any alternatives? That function in the issue you linked returns undefined.

Comment: That function is not supposed to return a value, it's supposed to create a way to parse this date format. Run that function, then call `Date.fromISO('2013-03-07T00:21:49')` to get the result.

Comment: FF gives me a day after the date IE 8/9 gives me. So FF gives me 2/7/2013 and IE gives me 2/6/2013???????

Comment: If I run the example I get 5/24/2012 and it should be 6/24

Comment: It is actually messing up the month and not the day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By far the easiest solution was to use moment.js. Make sure you save the file instead of looking it up based on a url for IE 8.