# javascript not executing when showing linear calendar (only on all version of IE)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

My client report a problem with the linear calendar on this page : http://www.portailjeunesselac2m.org/

with all browser it work except for IE (all version)

it just show the event without execution the javascript... i try debuggin it, but cannot "see" why it failed... can you get me some help please ?

because i do not know where to look, i will try to make html validate it... just in case !
i fix 10 errors !... maybe it can help !

*note 3 date must be highlight : 8, 10 and 24 october...

Comment: have you seen this error in your console:

`HTML1424: Invalid character 
www.portailjeunesselac2m.org, line 131 character 20
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'date' of undefined or null reference 
timeline.js, line 53 character 24`

Comment: The problem is here (timeline.js, line 53) `for(j = i; j > 0 && events[j - 1].date > tmp.date; j--)`. j = 1, but events is array of objects, with empty first 5 elements. And it produces an error `Unable to get property 'date' of undefined or null reference`

Comment: HOW if the date array is empty, chrome and FF get it right ?

Comment: I also checked the website in Safari, and it is also not working. The problem might be on the parsing of the date.

Comment: @menardmam Read my answer.

Comment: safary is broken too, did not see that... so FF and chrome is OK all the other are broken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here (timeline.js, line 53) `for(j = i; j > 0 && events[j - 1].date > tmp.date; j--)`. `j = 1`, but `events` is array of objects, with empty first 5 elements. And it produces an error `Unable to get property 'date' of undefined or null reference`.

First 5 elements are missing, because of

```
if (date == "Invalid Date")
    continue;

this.events[i] = {
```

It skips some events, but still increases `i` counter, leaving empty elements in array. Try to replace `this.events[i] = {` with `this.events.push({` and add `)` at the closing `}`. Or make all `date` valid :)

The date is invalid because `new Date()` is not recognizing "11 01 2014" as a valid date. Try to write it in a title as "2014-01-11" ("yyyy-mm-dd")

ps: as a quick 'fix' - replace `var date = new Date(eventItems[i].getAttribute("title"));` with `var date = new Date(eventItems[i].getAttribute("title").replace(/(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)/, '$3-$1-$2'));`

pps: tired of all the messages. This is how your portion of the code should look like

```
    for (var i = 0; i < eventItems.length; i++) {
        var date = new Date(eventItems[i].getAttribute("title")
                            .replace(/(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)/, '$3-$1-$2'));

        if (date == "Invalid Date")
            continue;

        this.events.push({
            name    : eventItems[i].className,
            date    : date,
            day     : date.getDate(),
            month   : date.getMonth(),
            year    : date.getFullYear(),
            content : jQuery(eventItems[i]).text()            
        });
    }
```

Comment: the date is written as the apps whant to have it, just like it work 3 years ago... i have modified the code.. no luck ! will check it out tomorrow i have been on this for too long now, i dont see anything right ! thanks.

Comment: @menardmam Read the  `ps` part of my answer. The replacement with `push` is good, but it just removes an error. `ps:` part will help you with dates.

Comment: quick fix applied, but it "remove or forget" dates.. and only one remain !

Comment: @menardmam you, probably, need `$3-$1-$2` if in the date in title you have first month, then day and last 4 digits - year. Just saw in code that you have a second set of numbers = 20 ))

Comment: i will output the date as you said 2014-10-08 to see how it go

Comment: @menardmam or change it with javascript, just write instead of `$3-$2-$1` the following `$3-$1-$2`. I did not know which number is month and date in your record.

Comment: after echo to screen the date... some come as 0 (month or day) i will investigate that more... will tell you, thanks

Comment: @menardmam Why won't you do what I told you?? 0 is showing because js is counting months from 0. Just write `var date = new Date(eventItems[i].getAttribute("title").replace(/(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)/, '$3-$1-$2'));` and remove all alerts, keeping the date in title the way it was. Or change the date in titles, keeping the js part as it was.

Comment: i just did exacly all the step/mods you told me, but it just got worst, i loos all the date marker... and now i am stuck !

Comment: Changing SO MANY THING screw up averything... i am getting a backup now and back to basic... will keep you posted

Comment: Getting back to last week, the calendar SHOW, but not the dates... it's 50% there

Comment: @menardmam you needed to make only 2 changes, thats it. Look at answer.

Comment: @menardmam http://jsfiddle.net/gr59t4wc/ This is how it should look like. There is only one date in October, which is shown on calendar. If you change the month - other dates are shown.

Comment: why a date supposed to be 10 th day become the 09 !

Comment: @menardmam because it depends on the timezone. By default it works in GMT/UTC when parsing the date. If you do not provide hours, midnight at GMT corresponds to the previous date in everything to the west of greenwich meridian. If you do something like this `'$3-$1-$2 12:00'` - it will work in most cases, but it is better to use timezone of the events listed on the website.

Comment: Or it is possible to take into account user's timezone http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2771609/how-to-ignore-users-time-zone-and-force-date-use-specific-time-zone

Comment: i will try to fix the timezone.... bt can you check the calendar WITHOUT event date appear on : win7 or XP on IE8 or lower....

Comment: @menardmam Seriously, it feels like I'm developing this website, not you )) Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11020658/javascript-json-date-parse-in-ie7-ie8-returns-nan But IE8 is almost dead, I would not care about it. As it follows from the link, IE8 wants `'$3/$1/$2 12:00'`

Comment: changing to $3/$1/$2 12:00 FIX the whole thing for all IE version and fix the timezone withou touching anything... again, thanks a lot for your great help, and coding changes