# Javascript Date parsing NaN in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

I get NaN error when I try to parse date from JSON in my Javascript

Format of date: **"2015-02-10T23:01:00.000Z"**

This is my code that works in Chrome but not in IE8:

```
            var sdate = new Date(entry.startDate);
            var sdateMonth = sdate.getMonth() + 1;
            var sdateDay = sdate.getDate();
            var edate = new Date(entry.endDate);
            var edateMonth = edate.getMonth() + 1;
            var edateDay = edate.getDate();
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff743760%28v=vs.94%29.aspx IE supports ISO Date format from version IE9+. So you either use some library (like moments.js) or change date string format.

Comment: It has to work in IE8 :s

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript JSON Date parse in IE7/IE8 returns NaN](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11020658/javascript-json-date-parse-in-ie7-ie8-returns-nan)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a direct solution yet reasonable suggestion in my opinion: [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) this will cover datetime parsing and manipulation for you.