# parsing a UTC ISO date to a local time date in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, parsing, iso

I have tried to search for the answer already, and although I find answers that are very similar, I don't think they are exactly what I am looking for.  Please forgive me if this is already answered elsewhere.

I am trying to parse an ISO date in javascript so that I can compare it to the client system date and display information depending on if the ISO date is before or after the client system date.

This was fine until I needed to support IE8 and now I am stuck.

I have created a function because I have three different dates that I need to do this to.

for example, my ISO date is:  2015-12-22T11:59  in UTC time.

but once my date is parsed,  the full date is 11:59 in local time, no matter which time zone i test, it's always 11.59 in THAT time zone.

I know that the function I have created currently doesn't do anything with timezone, this is where I am stuck.  I don't know what to add to get my end date to change as a reflection of the timezone of the clients machine.

any help or advice would be greatly appreciated. 
I am not able to use something like moments.js because I have an upload restriction.

Jquery is available though.  or plain javascript.

```
<script>
function setSaleContent() {


    //creating a new date object that takes the clients current system time. so we can compare it to the dates stored in our array
    var currentDate = new Date();
    console.log(currentDate + " this is the clients date ");


    //These variables actually come from an external array object, but I'm putting them in here like this for this example. 
    var destinations = {
        freedate: "2015-12-16T11:59",  
        courierdate: "2015-12-22T11:59",
        nextdaydate: "2015-12-23T11:59",
    }

    //fetch all the ISO dates from the array. 
    var freeDateISO = destinations["freedate"];
    var courierDateISO = destinations["courierdate"];
    var nextdayDateISO = destinations["nextdaydate"];


    //I am creating this reusable function to split up my ISO date for the sake of IE8.. and create it into a date format that can be compared against another date.  I know that this isn't doing anything with my timezone and that is where my problem lies. 
    function parseDate(str) {
        var parts = /^(\d{4}).(\d{2}).(\d{2}).(\d{2}):(\d{2})/.exec(str);
        if (parts) {
            return new Date(parts[1], parts[2] - 1, parts[3], parts[4], parts[5]);
        }
        return new Date();
    }


    //I would like this date to change to reflect the time zone of the clients system time. 
    //currently returns the date at 11.59 regardless of timezone. 
    //If i was in GMT  i would want it to say 11.59
    //If i was in CT time I would like this to say 05.59
    //If i was in Perth I would like this to say  19:59
    var freeDate = parseDate(freeDateISO);
    console.log(freeDate + " this is the converted date for IE")





}


window.onload = setSaleContent;
```

Comment: Do not use `new Date(…)` (which creates datetimes from local values), use `new Date(Date.UTC(…))` for utc values!

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution is to append `Z` to the ISO date to indicate it is in UTC time, such as `2015-12-22T11:59Z`.

When JavaScript parses that date as a string, it will then automatically convert the UTC date to the local time zone.

While this is simple enough with a parsing call in the form `new Date(str);`, it will not play nice with your parse call with numerical arguments targeting IE8 and other old browsers.

A polyfill for parsing ISO dates with timezone exists: [Javascript JSON Date parse in IE7/IE8 returns NaN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11020658/javascript-json-date-parse-in-ie7-ie8-returns-nan)

This can replace your custom `parseDate` function after some modification to take an input string.

Alternatively, implement your own custom date manipulater to account for the local timezone using the `.getTimezoneOffset()` method on the newly created date, which gives the time zone offset in minutes, but you will have to come up with a method of utilising the offset such as adjusting hours and minutes, due to the limited methods of the JavaScript date object.

Comment: I tried to append Z  to it before, and that worked perfectly when I was doing new Date(str). But that doesn't work in IE8.

Comment: I expected that to happen because of your custom parse code for IE8. Like I said in the answer, you'll have to do something with `.getTimezoneOffset()` and implement your own date manipulation methods if you cannot use any libraries. You could try appending it with `+00:00` instead of `Z` and see if IE8 can parse that as a string but I doubt there are any better solutions. Alternatively, see this IE7/8 polyfill for parsing ISO dates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11020658/javascript-json-date-parse-in-ie7-ie8-returns-nan

Comment: Sorry was trying to reply on iPad and messed up my comment.           I tried to append Z  to it before, and that worked perfectly when I was doing new Date(str) and did exactly what I needed, But that doesn't work in IE8.    That is why I created the parseDate function.   I know my function isn't doing anything with date parts to get the time zone and I don't know how to write it in a way that it can happen, or if I need to do some getTimeZoneOffset calculation.  But whichever I need to do,I don't know what to write to achieve it, and I've tried for hours and googled for hours.

Comment: Have a go at replacing/enhancing your custom `parseDate` function with the polyfill I mentioned in the previous comment and see it that works. By the looks of the regex in the polyfill, it should support timezones and should fix your problem.